# show submenuitems next to items in a combobox

Tags: wpf, xaml

I need some help doing the following:

i have a combbox and i bind the value of an enum to it ..

```
internal enum MyProducts
    {
        ProductA,
        ProductB,
        ProductC,
        ProductD
    }

internal enum ProductsValue
    {
        ValueA,
        ValueB,
        ValueC,
        ValueD
    }
```

...

```
<Window.Resources>
<ObjectDataProvider x:Key="ProductsObjectData" MethodName="GetValues"
                            ObjectType="{x:Type System:Enum}">
        <ObjectDataProvider.MethodParameters>
            <x:Type TypeName="MyProducts"/>
        </ObjectDataProvider.MethodParameters>
    </ObjectDataProvider>

<ObjectDataProvider x:Key="ValuesObjectData" MethodName="GetValues"
                            ObjectType="{x:Type System:Enum}">
        <ObjectDataProvider.MethodParameters>
            <x:Type TypeName="ProductsValue"/>
        </ObjectDataProvider.MethodParameters>
    </ObjectDataProvider>
</Window.Resources>
```

...

```
 <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource ProductsObjectData}}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="160" FontSize="16">
```

now, i need to show for each item in my combobox a submenu showing the values from the enum Productsvalue ..

So, when the user clicks on the combobox, the dropdown of products will open and next to each item in the combobox there should be an arrow when clicked, it will show a list with the productvalues ..
please check the image below ..
(it shows that the user clicked on ProductA, and choosed ValueB) [image])

Any help is really appreciated ..
thanks in advance

Comment: You can easily achieve this using a Menu and MenuItems. If you must have a ComboBox it will be more tricky.

Comment: Yeah, i need to have a combobox ...i tried the menu and menuitems ..looks not so good ...